# MySqlDataReader dataReader =cmd.ExecuteReader() pop up the window Form without getting into the while loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

My connection is working fine. However, when it runs to MysqlDataREader dataReader line, it displays the Window Form and does not access the while loop to get my data. I am using dataGridView to display the info from my database. What did I do wrong? thanks

```
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        //Create Command
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        //Create a data reader and Execute the command
        MySqlDataReader dataReader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //Read the data and store them in the list
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            list[0].Add(dataReader["id"] + "");
            list[1].Add(dataReader["name"] + "");
            list[2].Add(dataReader["weekday"] + "");
            list[3].Add(dataReader["description"] + "");
        }

        //close Data Reader
        dataReader.Close();

        //close Connection
        this.CloseConnection();
     }
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code snippet. Are you sure your query is returning rows? Also, you say winforms, but tagged this as asp.net. What is it?

Answer (score 1):

What is the command?

The Read() function advances the reader to the next record. If there were no records returned then the if will immediately be false.

So the command is most likely not returning anything. You want to do something like this (Where HandleRecord is just to make the code cleaner):

```
if(reader.Read())
{
    // Handle first record
    HandleRecord(dataReader)
    while(reader.Read())
    {
         // Handle remaining records
         HandleRecord(dataReader)
    }
}
else
{
    // Nothing was returned, do something
}
```

You also want to handle exceptions. From the code provided it seems that there is no try-catch-finally statement. If I remember correctly that should look something like this:

```
 try
 {
     // Contact database - read/write/whatever
 }
 catch
 {
     // Display exception to user, log, whatever you need
 }
 finally
 {
     // Close database connection and other cleanup
 }
```